# SQL: Joining sequential events based on time stamps

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have a table containing information about buses driving around a city. Each record represents an event where a bus arrives at a bus stop, with the bus id, stop id, arrival time (military time in seconds), and departure time (military time in seconds). If I can join each event to the subsequent event, then I can compute the time each bus spends driving between stops by subtracting the departure time from stop 1 from the arrival time at stop 2.

But how can I perform this join? How can I easily find the soonest arrival time after a given departure time? *edit* I am using sql-server 2012.

**Sample Data**

[image: Sample Data]

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Result After Join]

Comment: post some sample data and the expected result. also tag the question with the dbms being used.

Comment: dbms is sql-server-2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead` function, which gets the values on the subsequent row based on a specified ordering.

```
select t.*, 
lead(arrival_time) over(partition by busname order by arrival_time) as next_stop_arrival,
lead(departure_time) over(partition by busname order by arrival_time) as next_stop_departure
from tablename t
```

Comment: Beautiful! First time using the lead function. I'll have to learn more about it (and lag as well). Cheers!